# Is neo4j 4.0 embedded also requiring java11?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I use neo4j embedded in my integration tests.
I'm updating microservice to use neo4j 4.0 db which requires java 11.
Everything works fine when connecting to standalone database but when I switch to use embedded and add to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.8</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

causes strange situation.

```
mvn clean package
```

finishes with **BUILD SUCCESS** but every compiled class is removed from target.

Can it be caused because neo4j 4.0 requires java 11? How to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

The Software Requirements documentation for neo4j [4.0](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.0/installation/requirements/#deployment-requirements-software) and [4.1](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.1/installation/requirements/#deployment-requirements-software) specify the flavors of Java that are required for different situations and operating systems. All of them are flavors of Java 11.